# Boto 3 Redshift client execute_statement lagging

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, amazon-redshift, boto3, batch-processing

I'm trying to copy some data over from MySQL to RS. The table is 650,000-ish rows, so i'm doing it in batches of 10,000 or so and also using python's multiprocessing module. The first few iterations come out ok. The script pulls 10,000 rows and creates a csv file in S3 (Edited to mention that each such file is around 300Mb, so it's not really feasible to upload the whole data not in chunks, unfortunately), then copies the data from that file to the redshift table. But soon the script starts skipping chunks. It still uploads the batch file to S3, but the copying to the main table isn't happening. This last run took 34 minutes and here's a graph of the record ids (which should be from 1 to 650,000) that actually got copied to the table. You can see the jumps where a whole bunch of records didn't make it to the main table.

[image]

Does anyone have any solutions for this? I'm currently running it locally, but the same thing happens when i upload the docker image to AWS and run it from there.

```
from psycopg2.extensions import register_adapter
from psycopg2.extras import Json
import MySQLdb
import json
import boto3
from io import StringIO
import botocore.session as bc
from botocore.client import Config
import multiprocessing as mp

db = 'db'
cluster_id = 'cluster'
bucket = 'bucket'
rs_secret = 'rs_secret'

session = boto3.Session(
    botocore_session=bc.get_session(),
    profile_name='profile',
    region_name='us-west-2'
)

secret_arn = session.client('secretsmanager').get_secret_value(SecretId=rs_secret)['ARN']
config = Config(connect_timeout=180, read_timeout=180)
client_redshift = session.client("redshift-data", config=config)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def get_secret(secret_id, session):
    region_name = "us-west-2"
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_id)
    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    return json.loads(secret)


def upload_to_S3(data, key, session):
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    data.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
    s3.Object(bucket, key).put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())


def write_to_RS(query):
    try:
        result = client_redshift.execute_statement(Database=db,
                                                   SecretArn=secret_arn,
                                                   Sql=query,
                                                   ClusterIdentifier=cluster_id)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(e)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

table_name = 'form'
col = ['settings', 'fields', 'design', 'confirmation']
types = ['super', 'super', 'super', 'super']

table_name_full = f'{db}.{table_name}'

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

mysql_secret = get_secret('secret', session)

register_adapter(list, Json)

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(
        host = mysql_secret['host'],
        user = mysql_secret['username'],
        password = mysql_secret['password'],
        database = 'db'
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

iam_role = 'iam_role'

chunk = 10000
chunks = range(65)

def task(c):
    q = f"""
    select
        id, {', '.join(col)}
    from {table_name}
    where not ({' is null and '.join(col)} is null)
        and not ({' = "[]" and '.join(col)} = "[]")
    limit {chunk}
    offset {chunk * (c)}
    INTO OUTFILE S3 's3://{bucket}/raw/{table_name}_{c + 1}.csv'
    FORMAT CSV HEADER
    OVERWRITE ON;
    """

    mycursor.execute(q)

    key = f'raw/{table_name}_{c + 1}.csv.part_00000'

    query = f"""
        COPY {table_name_full}
        FROM 's3://{bucket}/{key}'
        iam_role '{iam_role}'
        ignoreheader 1
        CSV;
    """

    write_to_RS(query)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    pool.map(task, chunks)
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of places where this can go awry.  S3 file name collisions, S3 operations out of order, S3 object opened before data is added ...

The first thing to do is understand if all the data eventually ended up in S3.  The process you have should leave the files in S3 after it runs.  If you run a single copy of all the files from S3 into a new table are all the records present?

If not you are debugging your code to understand why.

If all records are there then you likely have an issue with issuing the COPY before the data write is complete or an issue with RS COPY commands failing.  Either way you should be able to check the messages that the COPY commands respond with and see what errors or row count loaded you get.

I suspect you may be overrunning the max connection (session) count for Redshift which is a hard limit of 500 for the entire cluster.

You may also be seeing issues with the WLM being overrun but this issue should clear with time.  However, there could be a timeout that is aborting some COPYs.

BTW you are using RS in a very inefficient manner.  10,000 rows in a file is quite small for RS and issuing single file COPY commands is also not ideal.  You would likely be much better off building the files in S3 first then issuing a single COPY command.  This would also have a good chance of fixing whatever the underlying problem is.  If you can increase the S3 file size to at least 100MB (1GB would be ideal) that would so have a positive impact on your run time.

Comment: I second Bill's suggestion to just dump the entire data into one file in S3 and using COPY to load it into Redshift. Much easier and probably faster too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! All the files do get added to S3. I'm checking now to see if they contain all the records. Each 10,000 rows csv is around 300Mb, so I don't think i can dumb the entire data, unfortunately %\

Comment: You want to have at least as many files in S3 as you have slices in your cluster, not just one.  If you are moving large amounts of data on to RS you will want files of at least 100MB in size with 1GB being ideal.  These rules will help maximize the bandwidth use between S3 and Redshift.

Comment: @BillWeiner ok i just checked and the records in all 65 files do have all 650,000-some distinct ids along with the rest of the data. I will now try just running the iterative COPY command on those existing files to rule out COPY failing because the data isn't finished uploading to S3.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly the files all eventually ended up in S3.  This leaves the possibilities that the COPY commands are running before the files are complete or that the COPY commands are failing.

Comment: @BillWeiner This is really strange. I ran COPY on the files in S3. The script took less than a minute. After it finished i ran `select count(*) from db.form`. It returned 80,000. Then i ran count again after a few s, it returned 160,000. Then 170,000. Then after several minutes 200,000, and finally 240,909. After that it was no longe updated. This is the exact same # of rows I got when I ran the script the first time, when it created the csv file and immediately copied the data. I'm so confused. I checked and all the data is there. How is it that it's lagging in the exact same way....

Comment: Let me make sure I fully understand the steps you have taken and please correct any mistakes.  You checked that all the rows are in the S3 files and they were.  You did this with a single COPY statement (or was this done by some other method?). You then ran the iterative COPYs (many COPY statements each loading 1 files from S3) and got the same reduced number of rows.  You also saw that the number of rows in the table kept increasing after you see that the code running the COPYs is complete.  Do I have this correct?

Comment: If the above is correct here's what I think may be happening.  First off you are using Redshift Data API (execute_statement call) which submits your query to a service that issues the statement to RS.  The return of this API call is that the statement has been received, not that it is complete.  Redshift can only run so many queries at any moment (<50 max but usually <15 depending on configuration settings).  Also RS Data API has a max statement limitation of 200 - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html#data-api-calling-considerations

Comment: RS also has a limitation of 500 active connections.  Now I don't know how busy your cluster is but is it possible that it is running into one of these limitations?

Comment: To know if these COPY commands are issued successfully to RS Data API you will need to check the status of the API.  Additionally if you want to know if the COPY statement completed correctly and with what number of rows inserted you will need to issue a GetStatementResult API call for each execute API call once they are complete.  Just because the execute API call gave you a 200 status doesn't mean that the command executed successfully on the database.

Comment: The "trickling in" of rows to the table is due (if the above is correct) to each file having its own COPY command and these commands being queued up by the database.  Redshift cannot run 65 things at once.  The best way to do this is to create all the files in S3, have your code make a manifest, and use the manifest while issuing a single COPY command to Redshift.  This is the only way to ensure that all the data shows up in the database as one single data change event.

Comment: @BillWeiner gah ... i don't know what the problem is ... i pulled up one id (90257) that wasn't getting picked up ... set the script to literally only pull data with that id. Saved that same record to its own csv. Copied from that csv into the main table. It uploaded to problem .... The record right before it also seems to be ok, What is happening. Are you saying there's a way to copy all 65 files in one go instead of through iteration? I'm about to try to figure out how to get request status cuz i'm not sure how.

Comment: Yes and that doing it in 1 statement is the preferred method.  Redshift is implemented on a cluster of computers and each one can independently connect to S3 to transfer files.  A single COPY command reading multiple files from S3 will be significantly faster than N COPY statements. See:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

Comment: There are 2 ways to to this - Load Listing and Manifest.  Load listing is where the FROM clause has a partial object key specified and Redshift will load all files that start with this partial object key.  "FROM 's3://mybucket/data/listing/'" will attempt to COPY in all files under .../listing/.  A Manifest is a file that specifies all the files that need to be copied into Redshift.  Using a manifest is ideal for automated processes as it requires that ALL files in the manifest be copied.  This prevents data corruption due to missing files.

Comment: @BillWeiner wow, that's amazing, thanks so much for all the help!